# Bound of Derivatves of holomorphic function.

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f$ be holomorphic in the open unit disc $D$ centered at $0$ in complex plane with $f(0)=1/2$.
>
> If $\left|f(z)\right|\leq 1$ for all $z \in D$, then $|f'(0)|\leq 3/4$?

If this hypothesis is true, can I find all such $f(z)$ for which $f'(0)=3/4$?

Comment: What is the condition on $|f(z)|$? I think you forgot to write something

Comment: Maybe use Cauchys integral theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Consider $g\circ f,$ where $$g(z) = \frac{1/2-z}{1-(1/2)z}.$$